# How many compositions of $n \in N$ are there where each part is greater than $1$?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Can someone help me with this?

Let $n \in N$. How many compositions of $n$ are there where each part is greater than $1$? (Number of parts are not restricted)

Comment: By compositions, do you mean [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)? If yes, you might read the Wikipedia article (and add the [tag:partitions] tag to your question).

Answer (score 3):

We know that number of compositions of $n$ in $k$ positive parts is $$\binom{k-1}{n-1}$$ and to each composition of $n$ in $k$ parts correspondes a composition of $n+k$ into $k$ parts greater than $1$ if each part we increase by 1. Conversely: to each composition of n into k parts greater than two each part we decrease by 1 we get a composition of $n-k$ into k parts greater than 1 so number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts greater than $1$  is $$\binom{k-1}{n-k-1}$$ and the total number is
$$\sum_{k\geq1}\binom{k-1}{n-k-1}=\sum_{k\geq1}\binom{k-1}{n-2-(k-1)}=F_{n-2}$$

$F_n$ is Fibonacci number

Comment: How do I prove the last result : $$ \sum_{k\geq1}{\binom{k-1}{n-2-(k-1)} = F_{n-2}} $$